# jquery sharepoint validate with PreSaveAction() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a small problem. I have an Checkbox which default is checked. When not checked, a div appears with fields (From Hour / From Min / To Hour / To Min). I managed to create this function with Jquery. My problem now is the validation of these fields. I read a lot off publications on the internet and tried these without any success. If i use the PreSaveAction() within the  $(document).ready(function() and place the validation within PreSaveAction(), Then the save button does nothing. I want to notice that i am using a custom layout for a form and the under  $(document).ready(function() the script for the custom layout is running.

I hope someone can give a advice for me. The details are on the screenshots. Thanks!

PS I don't have a lot off knowledge about programming.

Screenshots:

[Html Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LEU1.png)

[Javascript Details & Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4i0Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put the PreSaveAction function outside of the $(document).ready(PreSaveAction method will not be called within this function)

If you are using Custom Save button (to navigate to other pages etc after save) on custom list form, then PreSaveAction will not be called.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx